# Add data as an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which I want to add another array on it. Currently the server (php) respond this array as json data. Here is the sample.

```
[{
"id":"11",
"user_id":"8000",
"product":"Shoes A",
"quantity":"1",
"date_open":"2015-01-04",
"paid":"1",
"harvested":"",
"reinvest":null,
"profit":null,
"investment":"3000"
},

{
"id":"12",
"user_id":"8000",
"product":"Shoes B",
"quantity":"1",
"date_open":"2015-03-01",
"paid":"1",
"harvested":"",
"reinvest":null,
"profit":200,
"investment":"1500"
}]
```

Then the code of this is here.

```
$userid = $_POST['user'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_products WHERE uproducts_user_id = '{$userid}'";
$user_products = db::select($sql);

    $product = array();
    foreach( $user_products as $user_product){
        array_push($product, $user_product);
    }

    $server_msg = $product;

echo json_encode($server_msg);
```

Now I want to add an array which is the sum of user invesment's. So I'm thinking the code would be like this:

```
$product = array();
$total_product= 0;
foreach($user_products as $user_product){
    $total_product+= $user_product['investment']; // the sum of investment how to show this as an array?

    array_push($product, $user_product);

}   
$server_msg = $product;
```

So the above code, how can I achieve this so that the server response would be like this:

```
[{
"id":"11",
"user_id":"8000",
"product":"Shoes A",
"quantity":"1",
"date_open":"2015-01-04",
"paid":"1",
"harvested":"",
"reinvest":null,
"profit":null,
"investment":"3000"
},

{
"id":"12",
"user_id":"8000",
"product":"Shoes B",
"quantity":"1",
"date_open":"2015-03-01",
"paid":"1",
"harvested":"",
"reinvest":null,
"profit":200,
"investment":"1500"
},
{
"total_investment":"4500" // how can I add this here?
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways, but try this:

```
$server_msg = $product;
array_push($server_msg, array('total_investment' => $total_product));
```

That should give you the output you desire.

Comment: Thanks for your help! @rexmac

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with API (as it may seem), I best suggest to re-construct the structure of your JSON into something like this:

```
{
  "items": [{
    "id":"11",
    "user_id":"8000",
    "product":"Shoes A",
    "quantity":"1",
    "date_open":"2015-01-04",
    "paid":"1",
    "harvested":"",
    "reinvest":null,
    "profit":null,
    "investment":"3000"
  }, ....],
  "total_investment": 45000
}
```

To answer your question, @rexmac suggestion is one way. However you might not want to mix up your response fields. Surely it's ugly in the client side if you end up like this: (Assuming Javascript)

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (typeof data[i].total_investment !== "undefined") {
        totalInvestment = data[i].total_investment;
        //....
    }
    //....
}
```

but instead (way cooler):

```
let totalInvestment = data.total_investment;
for (let i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
   //....
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the idea!

Comment: OP, I highly recommend heeding the advice of restructuring your JSON response. My answer should give you the output you asked for, but I 100% agree with @Aldee, keeping your response fields separated will make handling responses much easier.